# Formula derivation for negative power

Tags: education

$$P={R * CCB \over 1-(1+R)^{-t}}$$
P stands for monthly payment, R is the interest rate,CCB is the initial credit card balance,t is the number of months until the debt is paid.

I would like to derive the formula for t ! 
$$-(1+R)^{-t}={R*ccb \over P} -1$$
 After this How should I proceed !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multiplying by the denominator and dividing by $P$ gives$$1-\frac{R\cdot CCB}{P}=(1+R)^{-t}$$ taking the logarithm on both sides we get
$$\ln\left(1-\frac{R\cdot CCB}{P}\right)=-t\cdot (\ln(1+R))$$
so we find
$$-\frac{\ln\left(1-\frac{R\cdot CCB}{P}\right)}{\ln(1+R)}=t$$